# get url of site from which user click our link

Tags: php

Any one knows how to know the site name from which user click our link.

Like the ads company site, how they know from which site user opened their site.

Like we send the email to many users and when a user clicks on the link how can we know about the site name from which user click our link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can check the referrer, which is set by the browser (mostly, it can and will be blank on certain requests).

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

It was spelt incorrectly in the spec, and the misspelling is here to stay.

Answer (score 1):

Mind: This variables must not contain info, they can.

```
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Answer (score 1):

> any one know how to know the site name from which user click our link.

The HTTP Referer header (although it is optional and can't be relied upon)

> like the ads company site, how they know from which site user open their site.

They generally add an account id to the URL's query string, and use that instead of caring where the link actually was.

> like we send the email to many users and when a user click on the link how can we know about the site name from which user click our link.

If it is an email, then there won't be a site (in most cases) just the user's email client. If you mean the webmail service they use (if they use one), then you shouldn't need to care about that.